How to create in python a network graph, using NetworkX library, and display it in Tkinter window
I'm developing a project in Python where I use the tkinter library to display the GUI of my application. The problem that i face is the need to present a network graph in my program. I've already discovered the NetworkX library that allows me to create this graph but I don't know how to display it in a tkinter window. Any ideas on how to implement?
I have already tried several approaches to the problem of creating the network graph, such as trying to create the graph from the browser and placing the browser in a tkinter window, I have tried just using tkinter to create the graph but I was unsuccessful in both, after searching on the internet I found this NetworkX library but I don't know how I can integrate the graph obtained in a tkinter window

Find a way to convert it to an image (png, jpeg, svg, ...) and display that in tkinter. Alternatively there is Canvas widget if you want to draw the nodes and edges of your graph from scratch.

as I remeber networkx probably use matplotlib to display it. And matplotlib has special methods to put plot in tkinter (or in PyQt). Embedding in Tk — Matplotlib 3.9.0 documentation

networkx uses matplotlib to display it.
And matplotlib has special methods to embed plot in tkinter (or in PyQt).
Doc: Embedding in Tk — Matplotlib 3.9.0 documentation
Create fig and ax as usually in matplotlib
fig = Figure(figsize=(5, 4), dpi=100)
ax = fig.add_subplot()

and use fig to create tkinter widget
canvas = FigureCanvasTkAgg(fig, master=root)
canvas.get_tk_widget().pack(fill='both', expand=True)
#canvas.draw()

and use ax in draw(..., ax=ax) to display it in widget
nx.draw(G, with_labels=True, font_weight='bold', ax=ax)

Sometimes it needs to update content on canvas
canvas.draw()  # update plot in widget


Minimal working code:
import networkx as nx
import tkinter
from matplotlib.backends.backend_tkagg import FigureCanvasTkAgg
from matplotlib.figure import Figure

root = tkinter.Tk()
root.wm_title("Embedding in Tk")

# --- create figure and axis for plot

fig = Figure(figsize=(5, 4), dpi=100)
ax = fig.add_subplot()

# --- create widgets - special canvas to display matplotlib plot

canvas = FigureCanvasTkAgg(fig, master=root)
canvas.get_tk_widget().pack(fill='both', expand=True)
#canvas.draw()  # update plot in widget

# --- create graph

G = nx.Graph()
G.add_nodes_from([1, 2, 3, 4])
G.add_edges_from([(1, 2), (3, 4), (1,4), (2, 3)])

# --- draw graph using `ax=ax`

nx.draw(G, with_labels=True, font_weight='bold', ax=ax)
#canvas.draw()  # update plot in widget

# ---

button_quit = tkinter.Button(root, text="Quit", command=root.destroy)
button_quit.pack()

tkinter.mainloop()



EDIT:
Another example which uses Button to replace graph in window.
I also put some code in different order to show that you can draw before you create widget.
It also has to use canvas.draw() in function change_graph() to display new graph.
import networkx as nx
import tkinter
from matplotlib.backends.backend_tkagg import FigureCanvasTkAgg
from matplotlib.figure import Figure
import random

def change_graph():

    #nodes = [1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6]
    #edges = [(1, 2), (3, 4), (1,4), (2, 3), (4, 5), (5, 6)]

    n = random.randint(4, 10)
    nodes = list(range(n))
    edges = [random.sample(nodes, 2) for _ in range(2*n)]

    G = nx.Graph()
    G.add_nodes_from(nodes)
    G.add_edges_from(edges)
    
    ax.clear()     # remove previous graph 
    nx.draw(G, with_labels=True, font_weight='bold', ax=ax)
    canvas.draw()  # it needs it in this place
    
# --- create graph

G = nx.Graph()
G.add_nodes_from([1, 2, 3, 4])
G.add_edges_from([(1, 2), (3, 4), (1,4), (2, 3)])

# ---

root = tkinter.Tk()
root.wm_title("Embedding in Tk")

# --- create figure and axis
# --- draw graph using `ax=ax`

fig = Figure(figsize=(5, 4), dpi=100)
ax = fig.add_subplot()
nx.draw(G, with_labels=True, font_weight='bold', ax=ax)
#canvas.draw()

# --- create widgets

canvas = FigureCanvasTkAgg(fig, master=root)
canvas.get_tk_widget().pack(fill='both', expand=True)
#canvas.draw()

# --- other elements in window

button_change = tkinter.Button(root, text="Change Graph", command=change_graph)
button_change.pack(fill='x')

button_quit = tkinter.Button(root, text="Quit", command=root.destroy)
button_quit.pack(fill='x')

tkinter.mainloop()


